# Generating Multiple Association instances using fields_for and partial only shows one instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model-associations

Previously I was able to render multiple instances of a particular association (Generating multiple roles that belong to a team  [Team has-many Roles - Role belongs to Team] but after making some changes to the layout it no longer does.  I have read through many related threads but none seem to solve my issue.

I have a multi-model form and I am trying to build multiple role associations and have them render multiple times in the project creation view.  The problem I run into is it will only render once.

```
#projects_controller.rb
def new
@user = current_user
@project = Project.new
@team = Team.new
@team = @project.build_team
#Default - New Project generates two roles through a team
2.times{@team.roles.new
        role = @team.roles.build}  
 end

#Models

  class Project < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_one :team, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :roles, :through => :team
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :team, :allow_destroy => :true
   end



 class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
      attr_accessible :name, :roles_attributes
      validates :project, presence: true
      belongs_to :project
      has_many :roles, dependent: :destroy

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :roles, :allow_destroy => :true
 end

class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :team
end

#Views
#new.html.erb
 <%= form_for :project do |f| %>
      <%= render 'fields', :project_form => f %>
      <%= content_tag(:button, content_tag(:span, "Create Project"), {:class => "btn- cma-2 bolds", :type=>:submit}) %> 
     <% end %>

#_fields.html.erb 
  <%= project_form.fields_for :roles do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/role_fields', :role_form => f %>
   <% end %>

#_role_fields.html.erb
<div class="formAreaWhite clearfix">
  <div class="width350 fleft">
    <p class="blue">Title:</p>
    <div class="formArea"><%= role_form.collection_select(:role_title_id, @roletitles, :id, :title, {:prompt => "Select a Role"}, {:class=>"formSelect", :size => '1'}) %>
    </div>


    <p><span class="blue">Skills:</span>6/6</p>
  </div>

  <div class="width350 fright">
    <p class="blue">Duties:</p>
    <div class="formArea">

      <div class="formArea"><%= role_form.text_area :duty, :class=>"text300" %></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I realized the issue.  I removed the fields_for :team  tag when I was making updates to the template since I wanted team values to be hidden but the association to exist.  Apparently the team instance must appear in the view in order for the role associations to be built.

Once this tag was added back into the view the instances of the roles generated as expected.